# How do I get F12 to break into the debugger on Vista x64 with VS 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, 64-bit, windows-vista

F12 is a wonder for tracking down UI blocking operations, but I can't figure out how to make it work with VS 2008 and managed code.

Help! Or not...

Edit: turns out it doesn't work in VS 2005 either on Vista x64, so I guess that either widens or narrows it down, depending on your perspective :(

MSN

Comment: What are you trying to do? And what command did you put on F12 in VS?

Comment: No command on F12 in VS. In 32-bit XP, hitting F12 while debugging a GUI application will break into the debugger immediately. On x64 XP and Vista, that doesn't happen.

MSN

Comment: Well, it's been passed off to another team at Microsoft, so we'll see where that goes.

MSN

Comment: Nope. I'm really tempted to close this.

Comment: A real shame there's no alternative -- I relied on this a lot when I was on x86 machine

Comment: Also missing the F12 shortcut on 64 bit windows, when wanting to debug "time critical" GUI drawing where one only have half a second to break the application.

Answer (score 1):

This is an alternative solution that preserves the convenience of hitting F12 at any time, even if the application "bites", without having to switch to Visual Studio and invoke "Break all" command as per my first answer.

Unfortunately, this solution requires one to add some extra code to the application we want to break into using F12. This special debugging code could be conditionally-compiled using e.g. DEBUG symbol so that the F12 functionality is not available in release builds.

The solution works by creating a background thread; the thread then registers a global keyboard hook and starts a form-less message loop. The sample application below creates a form on the main UI thread with a single button, "Sleep". When the button in clicked, main UI thread will be locked by sleeping for  10 seconds (Thread.Sleep) to simulate application "biting".

To test the F12 functionality, first click "Sleep" button, then hit F12 - program will break into debugger immediately even though the main UI thread is being blocked. The following screenshot shows currently running threads on my machine (Vista x64) after F12:

[Active threads on F12 http://img242.imageshack.us/img242/5189/f12threadsre9.png](http://img242.imageshack.us/img242/5189/f12threadsre9.png)

As you can see, the main program is still in the "GoToSleep" method, while the global hook is invoked in the background thread we created.

The global hook code is based on [Stephen Toub's article](http://blogs.msdn.com/toub/archive/2006/05/03/589423.aspx).

Now the implementation:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace KeyboardHook
{

    public sealed class SimpleKeyboardHook : IDisposable
    {
        public SimpleKeyboardHook(Action<Keys> handler)
        {
            if (null == handler) { throw new ArgumentNullException("handler"); }
            this._handler = handler;
            var t = new Thread(this.ListenerThread) { IsBackground = true, Name = "KeyboardListener" };
            t.Start();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (!this._disposed)
            {
                UnhookWindowsHookEx(this._id);
                this._disposed = true;
                GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
            }
        }

        public static void BreakOnF12(Keys keys)
        {
            if (keys == Keys.F12)
            {
                Debugger.Break();
            }
        }

        private void ListenerThread()
        {
            using (var currentProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
            using (var mainModule = currentProcess.MainModule)
            {
                if (null == mainModule) { throw new InvalidOperationException("Unable to determine main module for the current process"); }

                this._id = SetWindowsHookEx(
                    WH_KEYBOARD_LL,
                    this.HookCallback,
                    GetModuleHandle(mainModule.ModuleName), 0);
            }

            Application.Run();
        }

        private IntPtr HookCallback(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
        {
            if (nCode >= 0 && wParam == (IntPtr)WM_KEYDOWN)
            {
                var vkCode = Marshal.ReadInt32(lParam);
                this._handler((Keys)vkCode);
            }
            return CallNextHookEx(this._id, nCode, wParam, lParam);
        }

        private delegate IntPtr LowLevelKeyboardProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook,
            LowLevelKeyboardProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        private static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhk);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int nCode,
            IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);

        private const int WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13;
        private const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
        private IntPtr _id;
        private readonly Action<Keys> _handler;
        private volatile bool _disposed;
    }


    static class Program
    {
        private static void GoToSleep(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(10000);
        }

        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            using (new SimpleKeyboardHook(SimpleKeyboardHook.BreakOnF12))
            {
                Application.EnableVisualStyles();
                Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

                var form = new Form { Text = "Sleepy form", Size = new Size(160,80), Padding = new Padding(6) };
                var btn = new Button { Dock = DockStyle.Fill, Text = "Sleep", Location = new Point(10, 10) };
                btn.Click += GoToSleep;
                form.Controls.Add(btn);
                Application.Run(form);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While I did not know about the F12 functionality in x86 Windows XP, the following instructions describe how I'm breaking into already running programs (this technique works in both x86 and x64 Windows operating systems).

First, run Visual Studio (2008, 2005, 2003... doesn't really matter as they all support attaching to running processes; they inherit this functionality from the ultimate debugger, WinDbg, available at [Debugging Tools for Windows](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/debugging/default.mspx))

From the Tools menu, choose "Attach to Processs..." command:

[Attach to process menu http://img297.imageshack.us/img297/2369/attachmenuhe7.png](http://img297.imageshack.us/img297/2369/attachmenuhe7.png)

I find this functionality so helpful I even added this command to the main Visual Studio toolbar:

[Attach to process in toolbar http://img440.imageshack.us/img440/1232/vstoolbarmainaw4.png](http://img440.imageshack.us/img440/1232/vstoolbarmainaw4.png)

"Attach to Process" dialog will show up. It will list all the currently running processes (if your process is not listed, try enabling "Show processes from all users" or "Show processes in all sessions" checkmarks at the bottom of the dialog). Simply select the process you'd like to break into and hit the "Attach" button:

[Attach to process dialog http://img231.imageshack.us/img231/8415/vsdialogattachoq5.png](http://img231.imageshack.us/img231/8415/vsdialogattachoq5.png)

*Note: the debugger can work in different modes, debugging native code, managed code, scripts (in Internet Explorer) or even T-SQL and WF workflow. Whatever your choices, the "attach to process" dialog will remember them for the next time you open it.*

After Visual Studio successfully attaches to the process you're trying to break into, use the Debug -> Break All command to stop all the threads in this process:

[Break all menu http://img297.imageshack.us/img297/8579/vsmenubreakallrb1.png](http://img297.imageshack.us/img297/8579/vsmenubreakallrb1.png)

This command is also available from the debug toolbar:

[Break all in toolbar http://img440.imageshack.us/img440/248/vstoolbardebugwt4.png](http://img440.imageshack.us/img440/248/vstoolbardebugwt4.png)

After breaking, you can explore all the currently running threads, their stacks, memory, local and global variables, etc. This should allow you to troubleshoot long-running operations even from x64 operating systems where the F12 functionality you were using is not readily available.

Comment: In your question you're mentioning you're already debugging your application - in that case you only need to run the "Break all" command (because the process being debugged is already attached). Fastest solution IMHO would be to focus Visual Studio and hit the "Break all" keyboard shortcut.

Comment: It's not as fast as hitting F12. Or rather, hitting F12 takes **much less time** than switching apps and hitting Break All. Trust me, it's awesome when it works.

MSN

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that you have to have the kernel-mode debugger installed and running for this to work. I've installed various versions of Visual Studio on lots of different machines, and I've never had the <kbd>F12</kbd> key do anything special. I don't think it has anything to do with VS itself, you're just associating it because you happen to *also* have VS installed on the machine.

I recommend downloading and installing the "Debugging Tools for Windows" package included as part of the [Windows Software Development Kit (SDK)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/hardware/hh852363). (Or, if you're a driver developer, you might prefer to download the Windows Driver Kit (WDK), which also includes these tools.) Make sure that you select the "Debugging Tools" box during the installation. If that's the only tools you want to install, you can check that box and uncheck all of the others; they are not required components.

This will ensure that you have the Kernel Debugger (KD) and the NTKD variation, along with the WinDbg GUI, installed on your machine. These tools are all available for both x86 and x64 processors.

See more information here: [Windows Debugging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551063.aspx).